# How can I be sure my framework is not being replaced

Tags: ios

I am working for a banking company. We are developing a framework that will contain some security/risk calculation mechanisms. We are going to use it in our banking app.

I know this is an edge case, but regulations want this. We need to be sure if our security framework is replaced by a jailbreak user.

What is the best way to do this on the iOS platform? I am not sure, but it looks like I need to use codesigning. If this is the answer, I need a starting point or some example because I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validate an individual framework.

You can use [app attestation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity) to validate that your app, as whole, hasn't been tampered with.

However, even with App Attestation there is no 100% guarantee that your app hasn't been modified; An attacker could, potentially, modify the code in your app that checks the result of the app attestation process to ignore the result of the check and return true.  All you can do is increase the effort required by an attacker.

It is a fundamental of information security that it is impossible to fully secure a device that you don't physically control.

If you cannot mitigate the threat sufficiently then you should look to moving the specific function to a server-side implementation that you do control.